# How to find all columns of every first row in a group in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName 
0001          Mr.A  
0002          Mr.A
0003          Mr.A
0004          Mr.B
0005          Mr.B 
0006          Mr.B
0007          Mr.C
0008          Mr.C 
0009          Mr.C

Expected Output 
0001 Mr.A
0004 Mr.B
0007 Mr.c
```

i am expecting to see only unique EmployeeName with first occurance of employeeID.

Comment: What do you mean by "first"? Minimum?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by EmployeeName order by EmployeeId) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: it gives following error:
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
Error at Line: 3 Column: 19

Comment: @user2232167 . . . The parentheses are balanced.  Are you sure you are putting your table name in for "table"?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer using `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeName ORDER BY EmployeeId) AS Rn
   ,EmployeeId
   ,EmployeeName
)
SELECT * FROM C WHERE Rn = 1
```